# mysql 5.1 stored procedure limit variable

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have problem executing this proc in my hosted mysql v-5.1. I cant find the problem or error. please help me out.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `fetchTimeLine`;;    
CREATE PROCEDURE `fetchTimeLine`(IN `delim` int(10))    
BEGIN    
PREPARE STMT FROM     
" SELECT event_id as event,date,schedule,venue,members,descr,about,    
(SELECT src FROM photo WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 0,1) as photo1,    
(SELECT src FROM photo WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 1,1) as photo2,    
(SELECT src FROM photo WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 2,1) as photo3,    
(SELECT scr_shoot FROM videos WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 0,1) as video1,    
(SELECT scr_shoot FROM videos WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 1,1) as video2,    
(SELECT scr_shoot FROM videos WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 2,1) as video3,    
(SELECT src FROM videos WHERE event_id=event LIMIT 0,1) as vsrc1    
FROM activities    
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT ?,?; ";     

SET @START = delim;    
SET @LIMIT = 2;    
EXECUTE STMT USING @START, @LIMIT;    
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;    

END;;
```

error I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

Comment: welcome to the manual debugging of stackoverflow. What error you get ?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: problem solved. thnx for quick reply and efforts. it was may be delimiter problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `date` is a reserved word, and
you have it in your SELECT clause. Try

```
`date`
```

instead.

Apply the same change in your ORDER BY clause.

Comment: no luck. still get error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: thnx for ur effort.
its run now. may be delimiter problem.